# Add Bot to Skype : Change Capabilities section

Tags: botframework, skype

I have created bot using azure bot services and added Skype under channels.

Now, I have embedded "add bot to skype" link in my page using the below URL
https://join.skype.com/bot/XXXXXXbotappid

On click of this link, a page is opening to add bot to contacts. In that page we could see the default content under capabilities.

```
"Capabilities - Send and receive instant messages and photos"
```

We have to edit this content to add more capabilities to our bot.
Is there any way I can edit the capabilities and privacy section ??

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For the Preview version of a Skype bot at least, the 'Capabilities' and 'Privacy' sections are automatically generated by Skype, and are not something that can be altered by the developer when building the bot. The only changes that can be made to that section are if you disable the bot's ability to make messages, that particular bullet goes away, and if you allow the bot the ability to make calls, it adds in the -Make calls bullet.